Storing lexicographically ordered strings in Redis/Valkey
I have many strings and each string maps to a json. Is there a way to save the json data in Redis/Valkey ordered set lexicographically ordered by the string. Or is there any data structure in Redis/Valkey which can be used in this scenario.
I want to avoid getting the list of lexicographically ordered strings from the ordered set and then send a request to get the value of json from the hash using the string for every string.

What you're describing is accessible with Redis' Search and Query capability: https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/interact/search-and-query/
You would need to explicitly index your data, and then you can can order it lexigraphically:
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CREATE test ON JSON prefix 1 test: SCHEMA $.name as name tag SORTABLE
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET test:1 $ '{"name":"foo"}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET test:2 $ '{"name":"bar"}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET test:3 $ '{"name":"baz"}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH test * SORTBY name asc
1) (integer) 3
2) "test:2"
3) 1) "name"
   2) "bar"
   3) "$"
   4) "{\"name\":\"bar\"}"
4) "test:3"
5) 1) "name"
   2) "baz"
   3) "$"
   4) "{\"name\":\"baz\"}"
6) "test:1"
7) 1) "name"
   2) "foo"
   3) "$"
   4) "{\"name\":\"foo\"}"
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.SEARCH test * SORTBY name desc
1) (integer) 3
2) "test:1"
3) 1) "name"
   2) "foo"
   3) "$"
   4) "{\"name\":\"foo\"}"
4) "test:3"
5) 1) "name"
   2) "baz"
   3) "$"
   4) "{\"name\":\"baz\"}"
6) "test:2"
7) 1) "name"
   2) "bar"
   3) "$"
   4) "{\"name\":\"bar\"}"

